# Mybathis 3 set null params as empty string

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

Настраиваю Mybathis 3 в связке с PostgreSQL при попытке совершить insert в базу обнаружилась неприятная особенность: вместо null в запросе были сформированы пустые строки - ' ', из-за чего собственно запрос валится.

```
### The error may involve process_message.insert-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL:
insert into UTP_PROCESS_MESSAGE (
       SYSTEM_ID,
       PROCESS_MESSAGE_DATA,
       PROCESS_ID,
       OPERATION_TYPE_ID
     ) VALUES **(
       ,
       ,
       ,

     )**
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ","
  Позиция: 167
```

Я ожидал, что запрос будет сформирован иначе:

```
insert into UTP_PROCESS_MESSAGE (
       SYSTEM_ID,
       PROCESS_MESSAGE_DATA,
       PROCESS_ID,
       OPERATION_TYPE_ID
     ) VALUES **(
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null
     )**
```

Если передать конкретные значения, то все работает верно.

Параметры задаю так:

```
HashMap <String, Long> params  = new HashMap<String, Long>();
            params.put("systemId", null);
            params.put("messageData", null);
            params.put("processId", null);
            params.put("operationTypeId", null);
            session.insert("process_message.insert", params);
```

SQL запрос выглядит так:

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="Map">
    insert into UTP_PROCESS_MESSAGE (
      SYSTEM_ID,
      PROCESS_MESSAGE_DATA,
      PROCESS_ID,
      OPERATION_TYPE_ID
    ) VALUES (
      ${systemId,javaType=Long,jdbcType=BIGINT},
      ${messageData,javaType=String,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      ${processId,javaType=Long,jdbcType=BIGINT},
      ${operationTypeId,javaType=Long,jdbcType=BIGINT}
     )
</insert>
```

Исчерпал уже все предположения. В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот, стоило только опубликовать вопрос, как я сам заметил в чем дело... 
Надеюсь, это поможет другим. Проблема в невнимательности: 
символ $ нужно заменить на #, вот так:

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="Map">
    insert into UTP_PROCESS_MESSAGE (
      SYSTEM_ID,
      PROCESS_MESSAGE_DATA,
      PROCESS_ID,
      OPERATION_TYPE_ID
    ) VALUES (
      #{systemId,javaType=Long,jdbcType=BIGINT},
      #{messageData,javaType=String,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      #{processId,javaType=Long,jdbcType=BIGINT},
      #{operationTypeId,javaType=Long,jdbcType=BIGINT}
     )
</insert>
```